# Create custom environment in openai gym with game screen as observation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have made a game using PyGame. I want to use output of the game screen as the custom as the observation rather than a set of distances and angles. (I have seen the documentation to make custom environment but in that observation was not game screen).

Answer (score 0):

I would follow a tutorial on convolutional reinforcement learning. http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/

It is straightforward to extract the raw pixels from Pygame to form your observation array which goes into your neural network, the first few layers of which will be convolutional. There are plenty of examples available out there.
Google "reinforcement learning raw pixels".